# Kendo UI with Bootstrap wrapper issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

I am currently trying to use a mask feature from Kendo UI to mask the phone number input.

Once I introduced the js code:

`$("#inputPhone").kendoMaskedTextBox({
        mask: "000.000.0000"
    });`

my UI looks like this: 
[image]

It generates a span wrapper with the input tag, which is pretty annoying. 
Here is the HTML: 
[image]

Is there any way to remove this span? or basically silence this span? or any other better solution to mask a phone number properly?

Comment: Can you please share some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem has to do with `form-control` class. What is it? Can you remove it?

Comment: @Onabai for sure.

It is just some HTML code with out the span
` hl`
<div class="form-group"><label for="inputPhone" class="control-label">Phone number</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" value="1231231234" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
`

Comment: I tired to remove `form-control` it didn't do the work.

Comment: Can you show some example reproducing the behavior? You can use dojo/jsfiddle/... It works fine for me. Check it [here](https://output.jsbin.com/fobuxud)

Comment: Here is the link to the offical demo: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/mvvm

you can check the HTML code. there's a span wrapper auto-generated. and it messed up my styling.

Comment: The example that you mention in the link works perfectly well on my browser. I insist, the problem is with some of your CSS definitions and not with the span.

Comment: If you will use `kendoMaskedTextBox` then it is bound to create a dynamic `<span>` wrapping your `<input>`, so you would need to write some CSS rules targeting the `span.k-maskedtextbox` so that the element does not distort your layout

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, I believe that's the Kendo UI nature to have a span dynamically wraps the input. To avoid all the css hustle, I moved to another open source input mask tool.